# When I use BufferedReader to get HTML the parts I need are not there

Tags: java, html

So I put code like this to get a value from a tag in the site something of a site:

```
    try {

        URL url = new URL("google.com");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while (in.readLine() != null) {

            inputLine = in.readLine();
        }
        in.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

so say I need it to find  "Pizza"  but only some of the code pops ups so I cant access that part is there a way I can print the WHOLE HTML out (USING BufferReader and no extra imports like Jsoup), and then check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(input);
String inputLine;

 FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("orhancan");
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println(inputLine);
}

in.close();
out.close();

File fXmlFile = new File("orhancan");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);


NodeList prelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("body");
System.out.println(prelist.getLength());
```

There is a much easier way to do this. I suggest using JSoup. With JSoup you can do things like.[json](http://jsoup.org/)
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
    Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
Or if you want the body:

```
Elements body = doc.select("body");
```

Or if you want all links:

```
Elements links = doc.select("body a");
```

Comment: So this would save it so a file? So how would I read the file and is there a way to do it without a file? Also if I have to do it with a file could I save it in a folder? like the directory the jar  file is in like "Folder" but the xml saves it to a folder in folder

Comment: you can process in memory